# Qual é a diferença entre __str__ e __repr__?

Tags: python, característica-linguagem

Qual é a diferença entre os métodos `__str__` e `__repr__`? 
Os dois fazem a mesma coisa?

Comment: Aqui no SOen responde: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Answer (score 17, accepted):

O `__str__` serve para exibir o objeto para usuário final, usada pelo comando *print* e pela função `str`

O `__repr__` serve para exibir o objeto para o programador, usada pelo *console* do Python e pela funçao `repr`.

Exemplo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> str(today)
'2012-03-14 09:21:58.130922'
>>> repr(today)
'datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 14, 9, 21, 58, 130922)'
```

Veja mais [aqui sobre `repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr)<sup>(en)</sup> e [aqui sobre `str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)<sup>(en)</sup> na documentação.

Apenas complementando, no Python, existe ainda um terceiro método: `__unicode__`, que funciona como o `__str__` mas gera uma representação
objeto na forma de uma instância de *unicode* (em vez de uma string de
*bytes*, que é o que os outros dois fazem). Veja [aqui a comparação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods)<sup>(en)</sup>.

Comment: Interessante é que eu nem sabia que existia essa função `repr` :p

Comment: já agora, inversa de repr é eval :  `eval(repr(today)) == today `

Comment: Ah, então o `repr` é equivalente ao `var_export` do PHP.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters são duas funções bem próximas com mesmo propósito. No PHP ainda existe o `var_dump` que aproxima uma pouco, porém  a representação retornada é um código PHP válido.

Comment: Vale acrescentar que se você definiu apenas `__repr__()` e não definiu `__str__()`, então a primeira é usada como fallback da segunda. E `__repr__()` não possui fallback.

Comment: ultimo link ta quebrado

Answer (score 8):

> ## Resumo

### `__repr__`

- quando precisa do código que reproduz o objeto
- gera *output* para o desenvolvedor

### `__str__`

- torna o objeto legível
- gera *output* para o usuário final

---

As respostas dos usuários **[Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436756/2598310)** e **[Md. Abu Nafee Ibna Zahid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/2598310)** são muito boas.

Aqui fica minha tradução e remix das [respostas em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr/):

> ## Qual é a diferença entre `__str__` e `__repr__`?

### A implementação padrão é inútil

Isso pode ser um pouco estranho já que as implementações padrões do Python tendem a ser uteis. Mas nesse caso ter uma implementação padrão para `__repr__` pode ser algo como:

```
return '%s(%r)'.format(self.__class__, self.__dict__)
```

Mas também pode ser perigoso (por exemplo, é fácil entrar em uma recursão infinita se objetos referenciarem uns aos outros). Nesse caso [python](/questions/tagged/python) *se embola*. Perceba que é um padrão quando um deles é implementado: Se `__repr__` **foi definido** e `__str__` **não foi** o objeto vai se comportar como `__str__=__repr__`.

Em termos simples, isso significa: praticamente todo objeto que você implementar deve conter o `__repr__` que será utilizado para *"compreender"* o objeto. Implementar `__str__` é opcional, faça isso se você precisar da funcionalidade de *"pretty print"* por exemplo utilizado por um gerador de relatório.

---

### O objetivo do `__repr__` é ser [inequívoco](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/inequ%C3%ADvoco)

**Md. Abu** é um programador que não é fã de ***debug-adores*** e afirma que mal sabe como utilizar um e nunca utilizou nenhum com seriedade. Ele afirma que os ***debug-adores*** possuem uma falha básica em sua natureza e que acredita com uma *fé religiosa* em **`logging`**. Afirma com convicção que **`logging`** é a força vital de qualquer sistema de servidor decente do tipo *fire-and-forget* (dispare-e-esqueça). E concordamos que com [python](/questions/tagged/python) é fácil fazer [log](/questions/tagged/log): talvez com alguns projetos de *wrappers* específicos, tudo que você precisa é:

```
log(INFO, "Eu sou uma função esquisita e A é", A, "e B é", b, "mas tenho null em C — usando default", default_C)
```

Mas você tem que fazer a última etapa - certifique-se de que cada objeto que você implementa tenha uma **repr útil**, então o código como o citado vai funcionar adequadamento. É por isso que o "`eval` " aparece: se você tem informação suficiente então `eval(repr(c)) == c`, isso significa que você sabe tudo o que há para saber sobre `c`. Se isso for fácil o suficiente ou pelo menos de uma maneira confusa, faça isso. Se não, verifique se você tem informações suficientes sobre `c` de qualquer maneira. **Md. Abu** diz que costuma usar um formato similar ao `eval`: `" MinhaClasse(isso=%r, aquilo=%r)" % (self.isso, self.aquilo)`. Isso não significa que você pode realmente construir `MinhaClasse`, ou que esses são os argumentos construtores corretos — mas é uma forma útil para expressar "isso é tudo que você precisa saber sobre esta instância".

Nota: **Md. Abu** usou acima `%r` e não `%s`. Você sempre vai quere utilizar `repr()` (ou `%r` o caractere de formatação equivalentemente) dentro da implementação `__repr__` ou você estará fugindo do objetivo do `repr`. Assim você será capaz de diferenciar `MinhaClasse(3)` de `MinhaClasse("3")`.

---

### O objetivo do `__str__` é ser legivel

Especificamente, não se a intençao é ser [inequívoco](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/inequ%C3%ADvoco) - observe que `str(3) == str("3")`. Da mesma forma, se você implementar uma abstração para IP, ter o `str` com o valor 192.168.1.1 é ok. Já ao implementar uma abstração de data/hora, o `str` pode ser "2010/4/12 15:35:22", etc. O objetivo é representer de uma maneira que um usuário, não um programador gostaria de lê-lo. Cortar dígitos inúteis, fingir ser alguma outra classe - contanto que ajude com a legibilidade, é uma melhoria.

---

### Listas quando chamada o `__str__` utilizam `__repr__`

> Nota: Essa parte está bem complicada de traduzir, então comentários e edições são bem vindos

Soou estranho não é? Um pouco, como isso é legeivel

```
[moshe is, 3, hello
world, this is a list, oh I don't know, containing just 4 elements]
```

Legívle? Não muito. Especificamente, as strings em uma lista são muito fácil congundir sua representação de cadeia de caracteres. Em face da ambigüidade, lembre-se, o Python resiste à tentação de adivinhar. Se você quiser o comportamento acima quando estiver imprimindo uma lista.

```py
l = ['moshe is', '3', 'hello \nworld', 'this is a list', 'oh I don\'t know', 'containing just 4 elements']
print("[" + ", ".join(l) + "]")
```

(you can probably also figure out what to do about dictionaries.

---

### Resumo

Implemente `__repr__` para qualquer classe que você for implementar. Implemente `__str__` se você achar útil ter uma versão string que dá maior legibilidade em favor de ter mais ambiguidade.